Find files in a directory modified in the last 24 hours without using the "find" command
Is there a way to find the files modified in a specific directory in the last 24 hours without using the find command, using only the ls command?

Since ls offers no filtering on its own, the answer is easy: No.

you mean like ls -ltr and then pick through the list?

What is the point of excluding the right tool and explicitly requesting the wrong tool?

@KamilMaciorowski  My top three guesses would be "Because it's homework". Taking the title literally, I'm kind of hoping --maxdepth might be cause for a stumble.

Wouldn't know how to use ls for that, because its output is hard to parse. So, wouldn't use it, but rely on other things you'd need anyway.
What find does must be:

get the time now, in seconds since epoch
subtract 24h
check all files' modification time against that

We can do the same in bash (which according to your post is your shell) with the help of date and stat (assuming the GNU implementation or compatible)
#!/bin/bash
# enable recursive globbing
shopt -s globstar nullglob

# get time now in seconds since epoch
now=$(date +%s)
backthen=$(( now - 24 * 60*60 ))

for candidate in **/*; do
  # You only asked about files, assuming you meant
  # regular files – so ignore files of any other type:
  [[ -f "${candidate}" ]] || continue
  [[ -L "${candidate}" ]] && continue
  # get modification time of file
  modtime=$(stat -c %Y -- "${candidate}")
  # compare "less than or equal"
  [[ ${backthen} -le ${modtime} ]] && \
          printf '%s\0' "${candidate}"
  #       printing the file name followed by a zero byte (as safe delimiter)
  #       use \n instead of \0 if you want newlines (not safe, because files
  #       can and do have names with newlines in them)
done

That's it.
In zsh, things are a lot easier than in bash. It has glob qualifiers:
printf '%s\0' **/*(.m-1)

prints all regular files (.), which were modified (m) in the last (-) one days (1). No for loops, no manual stating, no calculations, supports sub-second precision where available and still no find. Just a slightly nicer shell.
Add the D qualifier to also report hidden files.
If no matching file can be found, zsh will report an error. If you'd rather nothing be printed, you can add the N (for nullglob), though you'd also need:
print -rNC1 -- **/*(ND.m-1)

Instead of printf as printf would still output one NUL character when not passed any argument. Remove the -N to print the files NL-delimited instead of NUL-delimited.

Yes, but I want the ls equivalent to this:
find . -type f -mtime -1

that's exactly what I'm doing. It literally gives you the same output. (using \n instead of \0 if you're not using find with find -print0)

How do you make it print new lines?

@SebastianLlaurador  There is no ls equivalent to that find command: ls has no test capability, and the output is intended for human readability, and is not (in full generality) parsable. If you care to post your Lecturers "correct" solution, we can explain why it is wrong.

@SebastianLlaurador as I explained in the answer, and in the comment: you replace the \0 from my answer with \n. Bit surprised you didn't find that in the answer – I explicitly wrote that!
